# Register Generic Validation with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, fluentvalidation, simple-injector

I want to register generic validations ( fluent-validation ) with SimpleInjector...

Here is what I tried so far:
**User.cs**:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**UserService.cs**

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IValidator<User> _userValidator;

    public UserService(IValidator<User> userValidator)
    {
        _userValidator = userValidator;
    }

    public OperationResult Add(User user)
    {
        OperationResult operationResult = new OperationResult();

        ValidationResult validationResult = _userValidator.Validate(user);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            operationResult.IsSuccess = false;

            ValidationFailure firstOrDefaultValidationFailure =
                validationResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault();

            if (firstOrDefaultValidationFailure != null)
            {
                operationResult.Message = firstOrDefaultValidationFailure.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }

        //TODO do your business here...

        return operationResult;
    }
}
```

**IOC:**

```
    Container = new Container();

    // I WANT TO MAKE BELOW LINE GENERIC...
    Container.Register(typeof(IValidator<User>), () => new UserValidator());

    Container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Transient);

    Container.Verify();
```

It's working right now. But as you can see, registiration of the validator is not generic.

I tried;

```
Container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(ValidationContext<>));
```

It's giving error on runtime:

> For the container to be able to create `ValidationContext<T>` it should have only one public constructor: it has 2

I also tried:

```
Container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(ValidatorDescriptor<>));
```

Another error:

> The supplied type `ValidatorDescriptor<T>` does not implement `IValidator<T>`

Last I tried:

```
IValidatorFactory validatorFactory = new AttributedValidatorFactory();
IValidator<User> validator = validatorFactory.GetValidator<User>();
```

But it's giving null validator. Because there is no attribute on User.cs class like;

```
[Validator(typeof(UserValidator))]
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

So if I understand correctly, you have multiple non-generic implementations for `IValidator<T>` (such as `UserValidator`, `EmployeeValidator`, `OrderValidator`, etc) and you want to register them all.

This is a scenario that is described in the documentation [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-registration) and you basically have two options.

Option 1: Register them one-by-one:

```
container.Register<IValidator<User>, UserValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Employee>, EmployeeValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Order>, OrderValidator>();
container.Register<IValidator<Product>, ProductValidator>();
// etc
```

Option 2: Use batch-registration:

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), new[] { typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly });
```

Here we pass in a list with assemblies that Simple Injector uses to search for non-generic implementations of `IValidator<T>`. Internally, Simple Injector will make the same set of registrations as we did manually with option 1.

Do note that your service classes are entangled with code that support validation. This causes lots of code duplication, increased complexity and can cause maintenance problems in the future. You should consider moving to a model using commands as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). This model allows defining valudators on commands instead of entitites, which allows defining a single generic decorator that allows applying validation to business logic.